# Fixing the issue of the IOS keyboard disrupting fixed elemtns

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, css, ckeditor

I have a fixed header on my page and also a ckeditor text editor.

I am making a responsive web style app CMS. The ckeditor on a mobile device takes up the whole screen with only the fixed header being shown.

To achieve this, the header is fixed, and the ckeditor containing div is also set a fixed. The editor is  faded in over the rest of the page.

When focusing on the text area, the header loses its fixed propeties and the user can scroll around the page with the header halfway down and then not staying fixed. The same happens with the ckeditor container.

I have looked this up and found that forcing a scroll may work, but it doesnt. Also tried re adding its fixed property, but that doesnt work neither.

Any ideas?

```
CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function(evt) {
  var editor = evt.editor;
  editor.on('focus', function(e) {
    $("#header").css('position', 'fixed');
  });
});
```